# Dual quaternions and arbitrary scales

Tags: quaternions, skeletal-animation

I have code that runs many skeletal animations using matrices, and I want to convert it to dual quaternions, to get better performance.

I have only one issue - I can't find a good resource on how to handle arbitrary scales.

I do not quite understand how the scales in the skeletal hierarchy carry.

Let's say for every node in the skeleton, I have its local dual quaternion (rotation + translation) and a 3D vector for scale, what do I do with them to incorporate the scale?

Answer (score 1):

Skeletal animation and scale, especially non-uniform scale, is a tricky subject.

Using standard implementation of skeletal hierarchies with a matrix per bone, scale simply propagates to children, which is usually seen as unwanted behaviour - propagating non-uniform scale would lead to shear and other deformations on children bones, that would cause strange artifacts in skinning. For this reason, it is often "compensated for" on child matrix - for example, see [Autodesk Maya implementation](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/API/class_m_fn_ik_joint.html) of this concept.

For a good description of integrating non-propagating scale into dual quaternions, several [academic papers by Ladislav Kavan](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~ladislav/kavan08geometric/kavan08geometric.pdf) provide a lot of detail. He also has a number of lectures on Dual Quaternions on youtube.

Comment: I do indeed need for the scales to propagate. My code implements a 3D model format which supports arbitrary propagating scales, so I don't have a choice in this (albeit the scale part, especially the non-uniform part of it, is actually not used much).

Comment: In that case, unfortunately, you can't represent the whole transformation using a dual quaternion and a scale vector - there are not enough degrees of freedom in these to represent shearing and skewing, which will be the result of non-uniform scaling propagated through transformation hierarchy.